# Where to get full source code for rt.jar?

Tags: java

I am searching the source code for rt.jar for Oracle JRE/JDK 6 Update 22.
The src.zip, which is included with the delivery, does not contain all sources, for examples the sun.* (e.g. sun.reflect.Reflection) packages are missing.

Where can I get a complete src.zip?

Comment: I don't think so. But you can use a decompiler (I've done it a lot :) )

Comment: JDK 7 now has every piece of source.

Comment: No, the Oracle JDK 7 is still missing a lot, like the sun package.

Comment: Here is an alternative JDK7 RT.jar source package with all publicly available source files: http://jdk7src.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## EDIT 2017-11-22:

This answer was written in 2010 where the world was very different.   If you just need the sources for the JRE classes, use the JRE in a JDK build - the included src.zip file is recognized by most modern IDE's.

If you really, really need the full source (if you are unsure, you don't) then find a suitable OpenJDK debug build or build OpenJDK from source.

---

## OLD 2010 ANSWER:

You can download the complete source code for the JDK from http://download.java.net/jdk6/source/

VERY IMPORTANT NOTE:  This is under the Java Research License, which may taint you in a way incompatible with what you need to know this for.

Comment: Note:  Oracle has decided to stop providing the Java 6 source under the JRL for new releases.

Comment: dead link, please update

Comment: @ShpytyackArtem It is 2017. Do you really, really need the complete source code for Java 6?

Comment: Yes, i would also like to step into the source code for the jdk 8.

Comment: @kiltek note that src.zip is included with any modern JDK which include source for most classes you will encounter in normal usage - eclipse discovers this automatically if you set the project JRE to a JDK.  Also note that unless you make a special effort, the JRE classes will _not_ have debug information.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen No i want to step through `sun.reflect.*` classes which are not included in the src.zip.

Comment: @kiltek OpenJDK for you then.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Thank you for your valuable inputs. Would you please suggest which others packages inside rt.jar are close sources apart from sun package?

Comment: @PratikAmbani I do not understand what you want to know.

Comment: Thanks for replying, well, I can easily access source classes of all, util, lang, etc packages except sun package. May I please know why?

Comment: @PratikAmbani Because only those classes you mention are in there?  src.zip is not covering all classes in the JVM, only those publicly documented.  OpenJDK (debug build) for you too.

Answer (score 23):

**sun.*** sources are a part of JDK that is *proprietary closed source Sun code* (or Oracle since 2010).

Having said that, the package you're interested in (sun.reflect.) happens to be included in OpenJDK 7, and all of OpenJDK source is open.

You can get the source here: http://jdk7src.sourceforge.net/

Comment: (citation needed :) but otherwise an excellent answer. +1 from me.

Comment: What about the JDK8?

Answer (score 7):

If you use Eclipse, here is how you can link to Java source files:

1. As Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen mentioned, download the JDK source http://download.java.net/jdk6/source/ , and unzip the tar.gz file to a folder, say 'jdk.src';
2. Open your java file that refers to a base java class (say Thread) that comes from the JDK;
3. Tap <kbd>F3</kbd> to open declaration, expect Eclipse to open a new tab with "source not found" message. It asks for the rt.jar source location, but you don't need to go through the trouble of compiling the JDK source to get it. Instead, click on the "attach source" button, in the "source attachment configuration" popup window, select "External Folder", then point to *jdk.src/jdk/src/share/classes* directory. Eclipse will then automatically load the newly found JDK class source code in the same window.

Comment: Thanks, but `sun.reflect.*` is not included.

Answer (score 6):

http://jdk7src.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK part of JDK 6 originates from OpenJDK or is integrated into OpenJDK. So maybe you find more insights here:

- http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk6/
- http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6
- http://openjdk.org/
- http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk6/

Answer (score 1):

The classes without source are closely based on the code from OpenJDK. You can download this source and you can see not only the Java code but the C code as well.  This can be a good resource for JNI examples too.

Answer (score 0):

Rustam is right: souces of sun.* are not available. But you can always decompile *.class and see pretty readable code (unfortunately without javadocs :( ).

Comment: The license does not allow that.

Comment: "The license does not allow that." oops. here goes the nice workaround opportunity! ;)

Comment: Modern versions of IntellJ has a decompiler making this much easier.