# Compiling Java API sources in JDK

Tags: java, jvm

After downloading openJDK from [here](http://jdk.java.net/15/), I found a `src.zip` folder under `lib` directory. This zipped file holds Java API implementations.

[image]

After unzipping this file, I do find a lot of familiar names. After running the following script in Python, it turns out there are 17733 `.java` files.

```py
import pathlib

print(len(list(pathlib.Path(".").rglob("*.java"))))
```

Now I am wondering if there is any possibility I could compile these `.java` files into `.class` using `javac` to inspect their corresponding binaries.

[image]

A similar post is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948926/how-does-one-build-the-java-jre-from-source-src-zip-in-jdk) but I do not think it resolve my confusion.

Comment: If you want to build Java yourself, it's what is currently the second answer to that question you should read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4949041/5221149. The `src.zip` file doesn't have all the source files, so it won't compile. Get all the source files and build scripts from the OpenJDK project.

Comment: @Andreas you know that the JDK, the OP downloaded, *is* OpenJDK? Or in other words,  you’ve linked to an answer that links to a page that links to the same download page the OP has used.

Comment: @Holger I know that the JDK that OP downloaded is a "build", i.e. the binary installable, not the source code with build scripts. I know that the link at the top of the question is for the "build" downloads, and that the answer I linked to has a link to the source. Not the same download page at all. Sure, the "build" download page also has a link to the source download page, but that's not what OP used.

Comment: @Andreas just consider that a decade old wisdom (“The src.zip file doesn't have all the source files”) might be outdated. It was true for Oracle’s closed source JDK 6, but does not apply to the open source OpenJDK 15. So compiling those java files into class files (this is what the OP asked for) *is* possible. It’s not possible to regenerate automatically created source files or adapt the JDK to a different platform, though.