# How to decompile a Java .class file from rt.jar

Tags: java, decompiling

I have extracted a .class file from the rt.jar file in jre1.7, and have attempted to open it using notepad++, however it is unreadable. How can I decompile the .class file into a .java file so I can view the code?

Please note that I am interested in the decompilation of the code, not viewing the source code provided in the JDK downloads.

Comment: Why don't you use the source zip file which comes with the JDK?

Comment: Refer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379050/where-to-get-full-source-code-for-rt-jar-jre-6-update-22

Comment: @Mr.Skeet with all due respect you provide an alternative to the solution.But what i am asking ,is there any way to decomplile the .class file into .java file

Comment: Why would you want to decompile the .class file when you can just open the original .java file that was used to build it, as @JonSkeet suggested?

Comment: @saurabhRai: In most cases, if you don't have *access* to the source code for a class file, you get into tricky legal territory if you start to decompile it, depending on your legal jurisdiction. Why would you want to get into that if you *really* only want access to source code which is already available? Note that the real source will be easier to read than decompiled code, due to comments etc.

Comment: @WATTO just for curiosity ,i want to know to the process for decompiling .class file into .java file

Comment: @Mr. Skeet as i am beginner in java so i was just curious to know the decompilation process,nothing else. Now i think i should stop thinking in this direction and focus on other necessary java related things.Anyways ,thanks for your response and suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Jon Skeet said, don't use JRE but JDK, which contains the entire source code. If you for some reason insist on your approach, then I recommend [JD-GUI](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui) for decompilation.

Answer (score 0):

`.class` files are the compiled binary files. You can't read the Java code from them, but you can run them. If you want to see the source you usually need `.java` files. These are either packed in the same jar but then the src folder, or they can be downloaded in a seperate package.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any decompiler tool like [cavaj](http://download.cnet.com/Cavaj-Java-Decompiler/3000-2213_4-10071619.html) for decompiling a class file to source code (java file). I'm using it, and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try any of the decompilers listed here:

- Procyon - https://bitbucket.org/mstrobel/procyon/wiki/Java%20Decompiler
- CFR - http://www.benf.org/other/cfr/
- JD - http://jd.benow.ca/
- Fernflower - https://github.com/fesh0r/fernflower

Or use online decompiler - http://www.javadecompilers.com/